# List if many without typing in R

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have the following code

```
n <- list(1,2,3)
str(n)
```

which outputs

```
> str(n)
List of 3
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 2
 $ : num 3
```

I would like 100 of these, but when I do

```
n <- list(1:100)
str(n)
```

I get

```
List of 1
 $ : int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

The difference is one list vs three lists. How do I solve this with in R? Also, how do you solve it with the `purrr` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?as.list` vs. `list`. Short explanation is that in your first example, you are storing three objects to their own vector within a holding list. For example:

```
if each number werre named:
> list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

vs:

```
> list(1:3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

BUT...

```
> as.list(1:3)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

`1:3` in `R` is a numeric range, thus if stored in a vector it is the representation of the range itself, whereas list(1, 2, 3) is a list, where the first vector is `1`, second `2` and so forth...